Autorize.net Hosted Payment Page Customisation
I customised payment form in authorize.net sandbox dashboard header, font and colour.
But these customisations not reflected when payment occurs. Payment form is still default one.Header is still not displaying, font is default. Preview in the dashboard shows the changes.
